# PHP preg_replace on correct one

Tags: php

So, I am using this to replace BBCode to HTML:

```
$text  = htmlspecialchars($text);

$advanced_bbcode = array(
  '#\[quote](\r\n)?(.+?)\[/quote]#si',
  '#\[url](.+)\[/url]#Usi');

$advanced_html = array(
  '<blockquote class="quote">$2</blockquote>',
  '<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="$1">$1</a>');

$text = preg_replace($advanced_bbcode, $advanced_html,$text);
echo nl2br($text);

public static function nl2br($var)
{
    return str_replace(array('\\r\\n','\r\\n','r\\n','\r\n', '\n', '\r'), '<br />', nl2br($var));
}
```

This works fine if I only have 1 quote, but If I use multiple quotes like: `[quote][quote][quote]first[/quote]second[/quote]end[/quote]`

I expect to get:

```
<blockquote class="quote"><blockquote class="quote"><blockquote class="quote">first</blockquote>second</blockquote>end</blockquote>
```

But because it takes the first [/qoute] it will turn into:

```
<blockquote class="quote">[quote][quote]first</blockquote>second[/quote]end[/quote]
```

I've looked it up but I cant find anything that is working for me. I am new to this kind of stuff.

Thanks.

Comment: please use modern solutions for BBCode, I recommend my own library https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode . Happy to answer any questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make replace until there is BBCode in the string

```
do { 
   $text = preg_replace($advanced_bbcode, $advanced_html,$text,-1,$c);
} while($c);
```

**[demo](https://eval.in/617062)**

Comment: This did the job! Thanks!